# Select a specific card reader to inform PIN

Tags: c#, smartcard-reader

I have multiple card readers attached to my PC, and if both the readers have cards inserted into them, how do I read certificate(s) from a specific card from a specific reader?

The readers have the same providerName (SafeSign Standard Cryptographic Service Provider). How can I select a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot distinguish between the cards using their ATR (more precisely, the historical bytes of the ATR), the only option is to read the certificates from them (or other on card content) and use uniquely identifying information within the data.